# How to update cells in a column based on entries in cells in another column?

Tags: excel, vba

If column C contains "100" then Column D should update to "001".

If column C contains "101" then Column D should update to "002".

This is required for a cell range in column C.

I tried the code below but it does not work.

```
Sub iflocation()
If activecell.Range("c1:C").Value = 100 Then Range("d1"d").Value = Range "001.Value
If activecell.Range("c1:C").Value = 101 Then Range("d1"d").Value = Range "002.Value
End sub
```

Comment: When you have trouble with code, it's much more helpful to describe ***how** it's "not working". For example, if there's an error, post the error message and the line causing it. If you're getting the wrong result, describe the expected result as well as the result of your code. That way, you'll be more likely to get quick and accurate trouble-shooting assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the fastest ways for the memory is to add the whole column to an array. Iterate through the column and save row indexes, which fulfill your conditions in collections.

```
Sub MainSub()
Dim vArr As Variant
Dim i As Long

'collection contains row indexes, where the value in column C = 100
Dim col100 As New Collection
'collection contains row indexes, where the value in column C = 101
Dim col101 As New Collection
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim itm As Variant

Set wsh = Sheets("Sheet1")
vArr = wsh.Columns("C:C")

'iterate through the array and collect corresponding indexes
For i = LBound(vArr) To UBound(vArr)
    If CStr(vArr(i, 1)) = "100" Then
        col100.Add i
    ElseIf CStr(vArr(i, 1)) = "101" Then
        col101.Add i
    End If
Next i

'call function which sets predefined value into column D
SetNewValueInColumnD wsh, col100, "001"
SetNewValueInColumnD wsh, col101, "002"
End Sub

Private Sub SetNewValueInColumnD(ByRef wsh As Worksheet, ByRef p_col As Collection, 
ByRef p_value As String)
Dim itm As Variant
For Each itm In p_col
    With wsh.Range("D" & itm)
        .NumberFormat = "@"
        .Value2 = p_value
    End With
Next itm
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not as useful as contributions that also explain it what manner the proposed solution helps solve the question... Stack Overflow strives to be a Question & Answer databank - a resource for future developers as well as the individual asking the question. If you could use the [edit] link below the question to add some explanation of how the code works that would be helpful :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update `D column` based on selection of `C Column` range then use selection and iterate all cell of selection like below.

```
Sub iflocation()
Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In Selection
        If (cel = 100) Or (cel = "100") Then
            cel.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "000"
              cel.Offset(0, 1) = 1
                ElseIf (cel = 101) Or (cel = "101") Then
              cel.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "000"
            cel.Offset(0, 1) = CStr("002")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```